# How to let a overlay view turn/rotate with the underlying views?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, screen-orientation

The code below works fine in one of two possible landscape orientations but when i turn the device 180 to the other lanscepe orientation the images i load are bottom up compared with the views that are underneath.

So what I have is a view (to overlay over the whole screen, that has images on it) created in code on-top of views created on a storyboard.

**And the QUESTION IS : Can the top left corner of the semi-transparent-overlay-view be drawn at the same place that the top left corner of where a underlying view is?**. I need the overlay view to turn with underlying views.

Here I let the view cover (overlay) the whole screen

```
self.overlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
```

Then I load up the images I like to show on the view.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

and here I set the image

```
[overlayView  setImage:image];
```

I have tried everything with orientation with no luck. Note that my app auto-rotates 360° so the status bar is always up top.

Hope this makes sens to somebody!

**Edit**: Here is the whole code used

```
UIWindow* keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
self.overLayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[[UIScreen  mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];

[overLayView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage1.png"]];
overLayView.tag = 1; //Used to remove the view in another function
overLayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5]; //Semi transparent

CGRect viewFrames = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 100, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 100, 75, 75);

self.exitHelpView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrames];
[self.exitHelpView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageOfXUsedToCloseWhenClicked.png"]];
self.exitHelpView.tag = 2; //Used to remove the view in another function

[keyWindow addSubview:overLayView]; //The view covering the whole screen
[keyWindow addSubview:self.exitHelpView]; //Image of an X
```

And in my .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* overLayView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet  UIImageView* exitHelpView;
```

Comment: Post the code that you use to actually display the overlayView in the view hierarchy. Are you adding it to a UIWindow directly? Or are you adding it as a subview to some other view that's already in the view hierarchy?

Comment: The code is posted :-) Im adding it to UIWindow directly. I tried adding it to other views but then i had a problems with removing touch to all but the imageView (with the X) on the overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you add to the UIWindow will not respect device rotations. This is one of the big features of the UIViewController--responding to rotation events automatically. If you can't find a way for it to work by adding the view to a UIViewController's view hierarchy, then you'll need to manually listen for rotation events and programmatically adjust the positioning of your UIView.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of something like that. Its going to be a battle adding it to the UIViewConrtoller hierachy (I allready tried) so Im going to try again to rotate the view by looking at where the status bar is. I really tried that also but without luck. But thank you for your help.